# Working on Multi-Package Composer Projects in PHPStorm

Tags: php, composer-php, phpstorm

I'm working on refactoring a huge PHP monolith (>1.2 million LOC, running >40 Websites in >30 countries) into some more manageable composer packages to separate concerns. Each of these packages will be living in its own GitHub repository, as some of them will be shared across all or just some sites, and some of them will only be relevant to one specific site.

Everything works just fine, except for the IDE integration in PHP Storm that sucks quite a bit (PHP storm sees everything as dependency, and excludes it from auto-completion by default. It takes quite a lot of configuration effort to make features like auto-completion and version control integration just work)

(Changing the structure as described is not an option. It definitely is the solution that makes most sense for us)

Comment: I have found this article. In short it is not possible, you have to open multiple projects but the good news are you can still commit.
http://dimsav.com/blog/9/git-repository-inside-composer-vendors